# What is the interior and boundary points of $Q×R$ in $R×R$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

What is the boundary points of $Q×R$ in $R×R$

---

I think it is the whole $R×R$.as $R$ is the boundary point of $Q$

---

For the interior points, I know the interior points of $Q$ is the empty set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly know that the interrior of $\mathbb{Q}$ is empty as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. One definition of boundar is the closure minus the interrior. Therefore,
$$
\partial{\mathbb{Q}}=\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\setminus \mathring{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{R}\setminus\emptyset=\mathbb{R}.
$$

From [the boundary of product formula](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Boundary_of_Cartesian_Product_of_Subsets),

$$
\partial(\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{R})= (\partial(\mathbb{Q})\times\overline{\mathbb{R}})\cup(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\times\partial(\mathbb{R}))=\\\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\cup\mathbb{R}\times\emptyset=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}.
$$

Intuitively, you can imagine the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a subspace $X=\{(x,y)|x\in\mathbb{R},y\in\mathbb{Q}\}$, which looks like the horizontal lines placed at each rational $y$-value in the real plane. With this picture in mind, it is a little bit easier to see why the boundary formula gives that result.